# How could one prove that there are no positive integers for which a given expression is a perfect square?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, square-numbers

How can one find all natural $n$ for which $6n-2n^2+32n^4+25$ is a perfect square? In other words, for which $n\in \mathbb{N}$ is $6n-2n^2+32n^4+25 = k^2$ where $k\in \mathbb{N}$. I am fairly certain that there are no positive integer solutions, however, I struggle in finding a proof for this. If there was a general approach for polynomial expressions, an explanation for finding whether it can equal a perfect square would be welcome.
I know of approaches using the fact that $k^2\equiv0,1\pmod 3$ and $k^2\equiv0,1\pmod 4$, however, I can't find a way to use this in this particular example.

Comment: I have searched a bit but cannot find something decisive, searched up to 100000 no solution, modulo up to 30 give nothing special. We can squeeze $(k^2−25)/2$
between two consecutive squares $(4n^2−1)^2$ and $(4n^2)^2$ but what next ?

Comment: One possible approach:  rewrite the equation $y^2 = 32x^4 - 2x^2 + 6x + 25$ as an elliptic curve over $\mathbb Q$ in Weierstrass form.  (This will require choosing a rational point to move to infinity; you can choose e.g. $(-1, \pm 7)$ or $(0, \pm 5)$.)  It may be possible to calculate the group of rational points of this elliptic curve, in which case you could then see which of the rational points have integer coordinates in the original parametrization.

Comment: This can be extremely complicated. A special case is the Mordell equation. Usually, we can use Faltings theorem to prove that there are finite many solutions but that does not mean that it is easy to find them.

Comment: @Peter Why was my answer deleted?There was a mistake somewhere?

Comment: @Tomita I can see it was deleted by the review committee which is triggered when a post is flagged or largely downvoted. It probably was seen as an ad to Magma, so if this was unintentional try to make more emphasis on the method used by the tool than the tool itself next time, you can also say CAS (computed assisted software) instead to avoid explicit naming. This is my guess.

Comment: @zwim  I understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

From where you left off:

$$32n^2 - 2n^2 = k^2 - 6n - 25$$

Completing the square on the $n^2$ term in LHS:

$$32(n^2 - \frac{1}{32})^2 - \frac{1}{32} = k^2 - 6n - 25$$

$$\big(\frac{k}{\sqrt{2}}\big)^2 = (4(n^2 - \frac{1}{32}))^2  + 3n + \frac{25}{2} - \frac{1}{32}$$

$$\big(\frac{k}{\sqrt{2}}\big)^2 = (4(n^2 - \frac{1}{32}))^2  + 3n + \frac{799}{64}$$

$\require{cancel}\xcancel{\text{We have arrived in the form } c^2 = a^2 + b^2. \text{We obtain, } n = \frac{b^2}{3} - \frac{799}{192} = \frac{64b^2 - 799}{192}. \text{ If } n \text{ is a positive integer, then }192 \text{ } | \text{ } (64b^2 - 799). \text{ However, there is contradiction that }64b^2 - 799 \text{ is odd, but }192 \text{ even}. \text{ Hence, }n \text{ cannot be integral.}}$

$$\big(\frac{k}{\sqrt{2}}\big)^2 = \big(4n^2 - \frac{1}{8}\big)^2  +  \frac{192n + 799}{64}$$

$$\big(\frac{k}{\sqrt{2}}\big)^2 = \frac{\big(32n^2 - 1\big)^2  + 192n + 799}{64}$$

> If $k$ is **even**, then $\frac{k^2}{2} \in \mathbb{N}$.

Hence, $64 \text{ | } \big(32n^2 - 1\big)^2 + 799 + 192n$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Assume $64 \text{ | } \big(32n^2 - 1\big)^2 + 799$

$$\big(32n^2 - 1\big)^2 + 799 = 1024n^4 - 64n^2 + 800$$

Clearly, $64 \text{ | } 1024n^4$ and $64 \text{ | } -64n^2$ but $800$ is not divisble by $64$, hence we have a contradiction, $\implies$ $n$ is not an integer.

$\require{cancel} \xcancel{ \text{ If k is odd }, k^2 \text{ is odd.} \text{ Then, back to the beginning: }\frac{1}{2} k^2 = \frac{1}{2}\big(32n^4 - 2n^2 + 6n + 25 \big) k^2 = 32n^4 - 2n^2 + 6n + 5^2 \implies k^2 = a^2 + b^2 n \in \mathbb{N} \implies 32n^4 - 2n^2 + 6n \in \mathbb{N}. \text{ Furthermore, } k \in \mathbb{N} \text{ restricts to the only triple possible: }\{k, a, b\}: \{13, 12, 5\}. \text{ Let } f(n) = 32n^4 - 2n^2 + 6n. \text{ Hence, we must have }f(n) = 144. \text{ However, } f(1) = 36, f(2) = 516\text{, indicating solution of } f(n) = 144 \text{ exists for n } \in (1, 2), \text{ and contradicting that n is integral.}}$

**EDIT:**

I cannot believe I did not think of this beforehand:

For $6n−2n^2+32n^4+25$ to be a perfect square, it can be least expressed in the form $(an^2 + bn + c)^2$ for some $a, b, c$ coeff.

Expanding, $(an^2 + bn + c)^2$, gives $$(a^2)n^4 + (2ab)n^3 + (2ac + b^2)n^2 + (2bc)n + c^2$$

Solving simultaneously, we first have:

$$\begin{cases} a^2 = 32, a = \pm\sqrt{32} \\  c^2 = 25, c = \pm5 \\ 2bc = 6, b = \frac{\pm3}{\sqrt{32}} \end{cases}$$

Since there is no $n^3$ term, $2ab = 0$. However, **both** $a, b ≠ 0$ and we have a contradiction. Furthermore, the irrational coefficients $a, b$ suggest that $an^2 + bn + c \notin \mathbb{N}, n \in \mathbb{N}$.

Comment: what about $b=\frac{29}8$ ? the parity argument seems insufficient.

Comment: Good point @zwim . Ill look into further

Comment: Even though $k^2=a^2+b^2$, $a$ and $b$ don't need to be integers, so no restriction to only one triple happens.

Comment: @Jeremy  but $a$ and $b$ are both defined by integral functions/constants (either $5$ or $32n^4 - 2n^2 + 6n, n \in \mathbb{N}$)

Comment: @Jeremy Let rephrase on $a$, $a^2$ must be an integer, as so are are $k^2$ and $b^2$, due to restricted $n$.

Comment: $k^2=32n^4−2n^2+6n+52\Longrightarrow k^2=a^2+b^2$ would imply that every perfect square has to be the sum of two perfect squares, which is unfortunately not true. Your argumentation is based on the assumption that $32n^4−2n^2+6n$ needs to be a perfect square, which it doesn't.

Comment: But does it matter that $32n^4−2n^2+6n$ is a perfect square? I think I forgot to include this (my bad): if $k$ is a natural and $b = 5$ is predefined as a natural, the only possible primitive set of both $k, b \in \mathbb{N}$ is $\{k = 13, a = 12, b = 5\}$. Ie. we could consider another set of primitives where $k ≠ b$, where there is a multiple of $b$: $\{k = 73, a = 48, b = 55 \}$. Lets divide by $11$, such that $b = 5$: $\{k = \frac{73}{11}, a = \frac{48}{11}, b = 5\}$. However, $k$ is no longer a natural. Hence, (conveniently) we pre-restricted $a$ based on possibilities of $b, k$...

Comment: ... without needing to consider $a^2$ as a perfect square. (PS: I think you made an error with $52$, in the original question $b = 25$).

Comment: Although, your question indirectly did raise a good issue, what if we consider $\{65, 60, 25\}$, I will edit this in the question.

Comment: Apologies, please ignore the comment before this (we already restricted $b = 5$, hence $b ≠ 25$ and only $\{13, 12, 5\}$ work).

Comment: Also, apologies for my other comments, I misunderstood your point completely, it is a valid point.

Comment: Your last paragraph seems to test whether the given expression is *always* a perfect square, doesn’t it? As in, your method would work for all expressions of the form $n^4+n^2+n+c$, for example, but of course $c$ can be adjusted to obtain a perfect square when $n=42$.